# What is this cap-like part?

Tags: capacitor

I found a huge cap-like looking part in an old parts bin of mine. I tried making sense of its marking and I don't really understand what they mean. I googled for the part number and I found eBay listing and such, suggesting it's indeed a cap according to the eBay category, but even there I didn't find further information about the specs of this thing (somewhere it was suggested it's a 40uF 1250V cap but I don't see 40 anywhere written on the part).

Testing it with my component tester delivers very weird results: it's detected as a diode but also with 1.8mF capacitance...?! (usually the tester works nicely and rarely lies to me)

Can you help me identifying this?

Here is the picture:
[image: Picture]

EDIT: Interestingly, while playing with it again, the tester detected it once as capacitor, with 1759uF and 7.9 ohms ESR. But I can't reproduce it, now it's back to the diode rubbish... Anyway, I don't get how to read these markings correctly.

EDIT2: Multimeter gives me 1755uF.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"1250 MFD" is 1250 µF — it's a capacitor.

"50 W.V." is 50 working volts.

Specifically, it's an electrolytic capacitor. If your tester is feeding it AC, it might identify it as a diode, because of the reverse leakage current.

When it does identify it as a capacitor, it isn't surprising that the value is off by quite a lot. Tolerances weren't tight to begin with, and this unit has some age to it, which probably means a lot of drift in the value.

You could try connecting it to a power supply of about 25V or so for a while to see if this re-forms the oxide layer. Pay attention to the correct polarity! If the electrolyte hasn't dried out completely, this might allow your tester to identify it more reliably.

Comment: remember to discharge it before connecting the tester

Comment: What does the acronym MFD stand for? Maybe "micro farad device" or something?

Comment: Micro FaraD as I understand it. it dates from before `µ` was a common symbol in fonts.

Comment: looks like there's a date code there too 3-28-75, looking very "manual rubber stamp". so probably made in USA

Comment: be careful, depending on the era and market, "MFD" might be milli or microfarad – however, in this case, a 1.something Farad capacitor would be much bigger.

Comment: Also note that 1250µF is pretty large – so I wouldn't even generally rely on measurements overly much. Usually, capacitance decreases with age, but yours might simply be within spec – many large electrolytic caps are sold at a 20% tolerance rating, so 1250µF might be anything between 1mF and 1.5mF for that accuracy, and no one says that a buffer cap from some power supply wasn't bought less with a percentage accuracy but for a *minimum* capacity.

Comment: A common tolerance on larger electrolytic capacitors is -20/+80%. The measured 1800 µF is well within the specs.

Answer (score 3):

The Cornell Dubilier Electronics logo is marked below the 50 W.V.

[image]

That company was established in 1909: [CDE History](http://www.cde.com/why-cde/history)

The company is apparently now part of Kemet Corporation.

I suspect that the "R" in a circle to the right below "Computamite" indicates that word is a registered trademark. It probably designates "computer grade electrolytic." I don't think that term is recognized as a standard by any standard publishing organization, but it may have an informal "industry consensus," (some would say honorific) meaning.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like a capacitor to me.  it says on the can 
50V (working) 
1250 Micro Farads